# Designing Database tables for models that share a lot of data with one another

Tags: database

I am currently working on an application that is essentially a group of individual forms that are comprised of modules. After the forms are filled out they are then uploaded to a database. Each individual module in the form is uploaded to a table for that module. Here is an example.

- Somebody opens a CombustionGas form (test data is entered into this).
- CombustionGas has 7 different modules with fields (Technician details, Pre-test data, test data)
- User fills these in and presses a button to upload them, each of the different modules is uploaded to a table with their corresponding name (dbo_pre_test_data, etc), an id number for the individual form test itself (CombustionGases in this case) is used as a key for the table.

Now this works well for most cases. However, some tests have the same modules but slightly different fields inside the module. So if there were 9 fields inside "Pre-test data" there may be an extra 3 fields in a different test. Currently, we have just been adding the extra columns to the table and setting them to null if they are not used in that test but as we have created more and more tests these tables have been getting a large number of non-used columns in them.

I am no expert on database design but this doesn't sit right with me and I was wondering if people had any advice on what best practice dictates when you have large amounts of shared data but also a potential for a degree of column variance like this.

Comment: look up SQL Table Inheritance or subtype/supertype relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the domain problem, but it sounds like you might benefit in the long run from rethinking how your tables are structured.

It looks like "modules" like pre-test data is actually not your "base" unit of organization for your data. This is because it has individual tests within it, some of which are shared across the entire module, others are not. It looks like each test needs a different table with a key to associate it with the parent module table. Specifically, the test table would contain records only associated with specific tests. The module table would then contain data that is unique to each module (modules only - not the tests that they contain). You can then associate them with a joining table, ModuleTests, listing the foreign keys of each of the Modules and Tests.

Caveat: It sounds like this is a field data collection app. The changes I've suggested above are most certainly breaking changes, even on a RAD platform. You have to weigh the benefits of normalizing the data vs. how long the application is going to be in use, and what you are going to use the data for. If you are only using this for one season, study, or whatever, then I doubt changing your table structure will be worth it. On the other hand, if your organization is going to use this app and its data for years, then it is worth taking a look into.

Further reading: [https://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Hands/dp/0321884493](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321884493)

Also, at risk of sounding obvious,: create a test server environment to test your changes. Don't just alter tables used in production.